# Why I can't see objects on top of retopology?

Tags: modeling, retopology

I have created a retopology mesh of a duck, but the eyes haven't been retopologized yet. I am trying to place the object of the eyes on top of the retopology mesh, but it's not visible. I am wondering if I need to retopologize the eyes as well to make them visible on top of the mesh.
Thank you !
[image]

Comment: Hello, do the retopology and you'll add the eyes at the end (and adapt the low-poly mesh shape so that it adapts)?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. I had the *In Front* box enabled.

[image]